# How to close android app in Delphi-XE5 Firemonkey application?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have this piece of code

```
procedure TFormMain.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  msg: String;
begin
  msg := 'Do you really want to exit?';

  if MessageDlg(msg, TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,
    [TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
    CanClose := False
  else
    CanClose := True; { FIXME: don't want to work on Android }
end;
```

It works perfectly on Windows. Application closes if I choose 'Yes'. However, application does NOT close on Android. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having the application close when the last form is closed is a Windows thing. An Android app will keep running.

To close the app on Android, call `SharedActivity.finish` from the `FMX.Helpers.Android` unit.

Comment: Or the `FMX.TApplication.Terminate()` method, which also finishes the Activity on Android (and does the equivalent action on other platforms).

Comment: @Remy On `XE7` for me, `Application.Terminate` returns numerous error messages in the IDE when debugging on an android device.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Such as?

Comment: @Remy Such as access violations (3 of them) - not seeking help, just a note. Not in front of it at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

```
uses 
  FMX.Platform.Android;

procedure TForm2.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  MainActivity.finish; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all combinations.

```
 - SharedActivity.Finish - NOT WORKING FOR ME
 - MainActivity.Finish - NOT WORKING FOR ME
 - Application.MainForm.DisposeOf - NOT WORKING FOR ME
```

This is works for me :

```
 FreeAndNil(Application);
```

Comment: It's a brutal way to kill your application.

Comment: Make sure FMX.Platform.Android is properly declared.

Comment: Did you try `FMX.Application.Terminate()` yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Not working... Even with Berlin Update 2, apps running in Samsung devices don't close properly. It's annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Calling Halt also closes the application.

Comment: With Halt, the execution path immediately stops. Your finally in try...finally statements don't get called. Your form's OnClose won't be called, etc.

Comment: Thanks Marcus.
By the way, I tried SharedActivity.finish in an application where I use TGuestureManager, it didn't close the application. it is still in the running application list. moreover when I try to activate it it hangs. Am I missing something?
When I run it in debugger mode. I get exception in TGuestureManger.Notification proceedure in 1st line.

Comment: Do you have any other activities running?

Comment: I new to android.. I call another window and then I close it... does that mean that it is still open? and if yes, how should I close it?