# How to fully close a Delphi-XE5 Android App

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

This has been asked before but not fully answered and I don't have the "reputation" to comment there. I want to exit an app for two reasons. 1. on startup if problems with the data files and 2. from a back-button press.

Another questioner got answers of using:

```
SharedActivity.Finish;
```

or

```
MainActivity.Finish;
```

Both appear to close the window but neither exit the application as in debug mode the program does not end in Delphi and the application is still running on the device itself.

Any more ideas? The hardware is a Nexus 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close android app in Delphi-XE5 Firemonkey application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234502/how-to-close-android-app-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-application)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy This is an extension of that question not the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Both appear to close the window but neither exit the application as in debug mode the program does not end in Delphi and the application is still running on the device itself.

This is perfectly normal for Android applications. The process will be terminated, eventually, by the operating system, as system RAM is needed for other processes .Please leave this alone and solve whatever problems you are encountering in some other fashion.

Comment: It seems a bit simplistic to just ignore it, at least for Delphi android apps. The apps seem to eventually go away when that state, but if you try to run it again, it hangs... that happens if its run again from the icon, or selected from the list of running apps button.

Comment: @DaveLane: "but if you try to run it again, it hangs" -- I cannot say whether this is a bug in Delphi or a bug in your app, but it is a bug. I would focus on fixing the bug.

Comment: Well, lets leave it at that until someone with Delphi-Android experience comments.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?
I'm facing a situatuon, where the app "closes" on back button pressed, but right afterwards I get a message "Unfortunatelly, MyApp has stopped."
The fact is that I want it to stop, but not displaying this message.

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me:

```
FreeAndNil(Application);
```

I tried these before, but they all don't work for me:

- `SharedActivity.Finish`
- `MainActivity.Finish`
- `Application.MainForm.DisposeOf`

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, please flag one of the questions as a duplicate instead of posting exactly the same answer on two questions.