# How do I make my Delphi code compatible with multiple platforms?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am currently developing a mobile application and my current target platform is Android (since that is the current device I have). However, I want to try and make it compatible with IOS and Windows (testing) as well

My current code for exiting my application uses:

```
uses FMX.Platform.Android


procedure TfrmMain.btnExitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MainActivity.finish;
end;
```

How do i make this compatible with IOS or Windows (when testing)?  Simply using Close does not work in Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close app in Delphi-XE5 Firemonkey application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234502/how-to-close-app-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [conditional compilation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29) to write multi-platform code:

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    // Do something...
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
    // Do something...
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF Android}
    // Do something...
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF iOS}
    // Don't do anything
{$ENDIF}
```

Also, take a look at this previous question for more details, especially for closing an application on Android:
[How to close android app in Delphi-XE5 Firemonkey application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234502/how-to-close-app-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-application)

Comment: HI Marcss, that I think is what will help me if there isn't a routine that is shared across platforms.....if not, then i will need those routines for each plaform. The routine I shared for Android in my question was taken from the same link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow make terminate you application. Because, only user decide, when he wants to close application. However, if you make close application, apple doesn't get your application in App Store.

You can use **Halt** procedure for it. But i don't recommend do it.

Thank you

Comment: I believe that is why my close application is in my btnExit event above. It is controlled by the USER.  I need a routine that is compatible across platforms, or I need a away to determine which platform and call the platform specific routine