# Segmentation fault (11) Delphi Mobile

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, IPPeerClient, System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs,
  Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Data.Bind.Components,
  REST.Client, Data.Bind.ObjectScope, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListView, System.JSON, REST.types,
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo, FMX.ListBox, REST.Json, FMX.Colors, FMX.Objects, gcmnotification,
  FMX.Edit;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    ToolBar2: TToolBar;
    Label1: TLabel;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    SpeedButton2: TSpeedButton;
    SpeedButton3: TSpeedButton;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    MemoContent: TMemo;
    LinkControlToFieldContent: TLinkControlToField;
    panel2: TPanel;
    ToolBar3: TToolBar;
    Label2: TLabel;
    btnExit: TSpeedButton;
    Label3: TLabel;
    email: TEdit;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    btnReg: TButton;
    popup: TRectangle;
    Label5: TLabel;
    btnOK: TColorButton;
    Label6: TLabel;
    procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Label5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnExitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnRegClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    gcmn: TGCMNotification;
  end;
const
  GCM_SENDERID = '460004329921';
  API_ID = 'AIzaSyBclEqDL-yFJRZZ6ESpBZLACJ27ROh7oao';
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btnExitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(Application);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnRegClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 gcmn.SENDERID := GCM_SENDERID;
  if gcmn.doRegister then
  begin
    if email.Text='' then
      popup.Visible := true
    else
    begin
      RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
      RESTRequest1.AddParameter('type', 'register', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
      RESTRequest1.AddParameter('regID', gcmn.RegistrationID, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
      RESTRequest1.AddParameter('email', email.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
      RESTRequest1.Execute;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Label5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  popup.Visible:=false;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue:TJSONValue;
begin
  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('type', 'select', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('table_name', 'person', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  jValue:=RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
  MemoContent.Text := jValue.ToString;
end;
end.
```

When im trying to running program, it installs the application to emulator but application does not starting. 
I got an error :

> First chance exception at $408839F8. Exception class Segmentation
>   fault (11). Process mClient.apk (1795)

```
unit gcmnotification;

interface
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.PlayServices,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  TGCMNotificationMessageKind = (nmMESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE, nmMESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED, nmMESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR);

  { Discription of notification for Notification Center }
  TGCMNotificationMessage = class (TPersistent)
  private
    FKind: TGCMNotificationMessageKind;
    FSender: string;
    FWhat: integer;
    FBody: string;
  protected
    procedure AssignTo(Dest: TPersistent); override;
  public
    { Unique identificator for determenation notification in Notification list }
    property Kind: TGCMNotificationMessageKind read FKind write FKind;
    property Sender: string read FSender write FSender;
    property What: integer read FWhat write FWhat;
    property Body: string read FBody write FBody;
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TOnReceiveGCMNotification = procedure (Sender: TObject; ANotification: TGCMNotificationMessage) of object;

  TGCMNotification = class(TComponent)
  strict private
    { Private declarations }
    FRegistrationID: string;
    FSenderID: string;
    FOnReceiveGCMNotification: TOnReceiveGCMNotification;
    FReceiver: JBroadcastReceiver;
    FAlreadyRegistered: boolean;
    function CheckPlayServicesSupport: boolean;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function DoRegister: boolean;
    function GetGCMInstance: JGoogleCloudMessaging;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property SenderID: string read FSenderID write FSenderID;
    property RegistrationID: string read FRegistrationID write FRegistrationID;
    property OnReceiveGCMNotification: TOnReceiveGCMNotification read FOnReceiveGCMNotification write FOnReceiveGCMNotification;
  end;

{$ENDIF}
implementation
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
uses
  uGCMReceiver;


{ TGCMNotification }
function TGCMNotification.CheckPlayServicesSupport: boolean;
var
  resultCode: integer;
begin
  resultCode := TJGooglePlayServicesUtil.JavaClass.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(SharedActivity);
  result := (resultCode = TJConnectionResult.JavaClass.SUCCESS);
end;

constructor TGCMNotification.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  Filter: JIntentFilter;
begin
  inherited;
  Filter := TJIntentFilter.Create;
  FReceiver := TJGCMReceiver.Create(Self);
  SharedActivity.registerReceiver(FReceiver, Filter);
  FAlreadyRegistered := false;
end;

destructor TGCMNotification.Destroy;
begin
  SharedActivity.unregisterReceiver(FReceiver);
  FReceiver := nil;
  inherited;
end;

function TGCMNotification.DoRegister: boolean;
var
  p: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  gcm: JGoogleCloudMessaging;
begin
  if FAlreadyRegistered then
    result := true
  else
  begin
    if CheckPlayServicesSupport then
    begin
      gcm := GetGCMInstance;
      p := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
      p.Items[0] := StringToJString(FSenderID);
      FRegistrationID := JStringToString(gcm.register(p));
      FAlreadyRegistered := (FRegistrationID <> '');
      result := FAlreadyRegistered;
    end
    else
      result := false;
  end;
end;

function TGCMNotification.GetGCMInstance: JGoogleCloudMessaging;
begin
  result := TJGoogleCloudMessaging.JavaClass.getInstance(SharedActivity.getApplicationContext);
end;

{ TGCMNotificationMessage }

procedure TGCMNotificationMessage.AssignTo(Dest: TPersistent);
var
  DestNotification: TGCMNotificationMessage;
begin
  if Dest is TGCMNotificationMessage then
  begin
    DestNotification := Dest as TGCMNotificationMessage;
    DestNotification.Kind := Kind;
    DestNotification.What := What;
    DestNotification.Sender := Sender;
    DestNotification.Body := Body;
  end
  else
    inherited AssignTo(Dest);
end;

constructor TGCMNotificationMessage.Create;
begin
  Body := '';
end;
{$ENDIF}
end.
```

Thanks for helping..

Comment: Where is gcmn instantiated. And why FreeAndNil on Application? That's surely wrong?

Comment: gcmn is in notification.pas, i edited my post

Comment: oh okay, i forgot. But another question, how can i close application?FreeAndNil on Application (is it wrong?)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure closing the main form will work on Android. That question was covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234502/how-to-close-android-app-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there are more problems than this, but the most obvious ones are:

1. You don't instantiate `gcmn`.
2. You must not explicitly destroy the `Application` object.